# How can I do a Trigger in SQL?

Tags: sql

I am trying to learn about triggers, I know how to do really basic ones, but I can't wrap my head around this. I have two tables Services(master) and Sales.

```
Services(ServiceID,ServiceCost,SalesTotal)
Sales(TransactionID,TransactionDate,Amount,ServiceID)
```

I am trying to write trigger for Update,Delete,Insert. When ever you enter a new sale in the Sales table, the SalesTotal will get updated in the Services table according to ServiceID.

ex:

```
INSERT INTO Sales(TransactionID,TransactionDate,Amount,ServiceID)
VALUES ('16','2014-11-19','50','101');
```

So if the SalesTotal for TransactionID '101' was 1000, after the insert it would be 1050 and the opposite if I deleted/updated.

I think I have to use join tables, but I am currently stumped.

Comment: SQL syntax is different for every DB engine. Which one do you use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this trigger, or split insert / dalete / update:
Code:

`CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[t_Update_Services] on Sales AFTER UPDATE,INSERT, DELETE`

AS

BEGIN

UPDATE a
  SET SalesTotal = SalesTotal - b.Amount
  FROM Services a
  JOIN deleted b ON a.ServiceID = b.ServiceID

UPDATE a
  SET SalesTotal = SalesTotal + b.Amount
  FROM Services a
  JOIN inserted b ON a.ServiceID = b.ServiceID

END

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I have a question though. How come when you join the tables, you have to state 'deleted' or 'inserted'?

Comment: Its sys temporary tables for triggers. If you delete some values from Sales, original deleted rows is in temporary deleted. If you insert, you can catch inserted values from table inserted. inserted/ deleted have same structure as original. But you can use it only in triggers

Comment: If you UPDATE rows, original values is in deleted and new updated values is in inserted. Because sql server at the first delete original rows and then insert new row with new values

Comment: this tables existing only in 1 session

Answer (score 0):

Add this inside the trigger

```
BEGIN
if exists (select * from deleted)
begin
    UPDATE Services
     SET SalesTotal = SalesTotal - deleted.Amount
     FROM Services  
     JOIN deleted    ON Services.ServiceID = deleted.ServiceID
end 
else  
begin
    UPDATE Services
    SET SalesTotal = SalesTotal + inserted   .Amount
    FROM Services  
    JOIN inserted   ON Services.ServiceID = inserted.ServiceID
end
END
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but Matej answered first so I gave him the acceptance for the answer.